# iPhone 7 and 7 Plus compatibility and showing compatibility in the app store

Tags: ios, ios10

For iPhone 6, 6 Plus, we had to add LaunchScreen, splash image and few changes in settings that would show the app is compatible for iPhone 6 and 6 plus.

How the app will know device for new device ? Is it only with LaunchScreen ?

Does there any rules which will show iPhone 7, 7 plus compatibility in app store for this new device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your app has **support for iOS 10** (and in your situation model: it was **also** previously compatible for iPhone 6 / 6S / Plus), yes, it is set to be **compatible for iPhone 7 / 7 Plus.**

The minimum iOS supported on the iPhone 7 is iOS version 10, that's way you have to support it in your project to be reachable by iPhone 7.

Answer (score 2):

> For iPhone 6, 6 Plus, we had to add LaunchScreen, splash image and few changes in settings that would show the app is compatible for iPhone 6 and 6 plus.

This was only necessary because the iPhone 6 and 6+ had different screen resolutions than any previous iPhones. (The same thing also happened when the iPhone 5 came out.)

The iPhone 7 / 7+ have the same screen resolution as the iPhone 6 / 6+, so no changes to applications are needed.